# Error in creating menu in android

Tags: java, android, options-menu

I am trying to create a menu in android. But it results only in blank page with text only. Menu is not coming on the screen. code is given below

```
public class SimpleOptionMenu extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon and text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
    }
    return true;

} }
```

please help to solve this problem.

Comment: can you show your menu.xml file here, the code was correct

Comment: Can you please provide the xml file? The code above looks good.

Comment: > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> 
> <menu
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:id="@+id/icon"
>         android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
>     <item android:id="@+id/text"
>         android:title="Text" />
>     <item android:id="@+id/icontext"
>         android:title="Icon and text"
>         android:icon="@drawable/icon" /> </menu>
----

Answer (score 1):

When you will press Menu key on your phone you will see the menu

Comment: There's menu button on emulator too.

Comment: In my emulator there is no menu button from where i can find that